# None type unaccounted for

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
       x_1  x_2      x_3    x_4        x_5  ID  cost 
0  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93     lightz  10     2       
1  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93     lightz  10     5       
2  354  abc  94mmm4k             heavy  15     2       
3  354  abc  94mmm4k             heavy  15     1       
4  354  abc  94mmm4k   455h             15     7       
5  354  abc  94mmm4k             super   3     2       
6  354  abc  94mmm4k    53g             10     4   
7  354  abc  94mmm4k    53g             10     4
```

I am using the following to get an aggregate count plus the sum of the cost column:

```
df2 = df.fillna('').groupby(['x_1','x_2','x_3','x_4','x_5','ID'])['cost'].agg(['count','sum'])
```

This returns what I expect, which is:

```
   x_1  x_2      x_3    x_4        x_5  ID  cost count sum
0  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93     lightz  10     2     2   7
1  354  abc  94mmm4k             heavy  15     2     2   3 
2  354  abc  94mmm4k   455h             15     7     1   7
3  354  abc  94mmm4k             super   3     2     1   2
4  354  abc  94mmm4k    53g             10     4     2   8
```

I'm then merging this dataframe with another dataframe to compare aggregate counts by using:

```
y_merge_cols = ['y_1','y_2','y_3','y_4','y_5','ID']
x_merge_cols = ['x_1','x_2','x_3','x_4','x_5','ID']

d1 = df1.merge(con_subs_df, left_on=y_merge_cols, right_on=x_merge_cols, how='left')
```

My output is:

```
   y_1  y_2      y_3    y_4       y_5  y_id    y_count   count sum
0  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93     lightz   10         12      2   7
1  354  abc  94mmm4k             heavy   15         24                 
2  354  abc  94mmm4k   455h              15         72                
3  354  abc  94mmm4k             super    3         21                
4  354  abc  94mmm4k    53g              10         42
```

but I would expect to see:

```
   y_1  y_2      y_3    y_4       y_5  y_id    y_count   count sum
0  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93     lightz   10         12       2   7
1  354  abc  94mmm4k             heavy   15         24       2   3     
2  354  abc  94mmm4k   455h              15         72       1   7     
3  354  abc  94mmm4k             super    3         21       1   2     
4  354  abc  94mmm4k    53g              10         42       2   8
```

instead.

For some reason when I merge my columns the count and sum that was done on `df2` do not take into account empty or NaN combinations and the aggregate count and sum are not displayed like it did previous to the merge.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: You need to show con_subs_df.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When performing the first `groupby`, you also fill all nan values `df2 = df.fillna('').groupby(...)`. Therefore, during the `merge`, you need to make sure both dataframes have had their nan values replaced by `''`.

There are some variable issues with the code in the question (e.g., is `df2` from the `groupby` equal to `df1` or `con_subs_df` in teh merge), so I created a small example with a self merge, the input data is the first dataframe `df` in the question.

First the `groupby` (same as in the question):

```
df2 = df.fillna('').groupby(['x_1','x_2','x_3','x_4','x_5','ID'])['cost'].agg(['count','sum']).reset_index()
```

In the merge, since the columns of both dataframes are the same, we can use the `on` parameter instead of `left_on` and `right_on`. Here we do the `merge` with the previous `df` dataframe.

- Without `fillna('')`:

  ```
  df1 = df.merge(df2, on=['x_1','x_2','x_3','x_4','x_5','ID'], how='left')

      x_1 x_2     x_3   x_4      x_5  ID  cost    count   sum
  0   159 xyz 883nne2 28h93   lightz  10     2      2.0   7.0
  1   159 xyz 883nne2 28h93   lightz  10     5      2.0   7.0
  2   354 abc 94mmm4k   NaN    heavy  15     2      NaN   NaN
  3   354 abc 94mmm4k   NaN    heavy  15     1      NaN   NaN
  4   354 abc 94mmm4k  455h      NaN  15     7      NaN   NaN
  5   354 abc 94mmm4k   NaN    super  3      2      NaN   NaN
  6   354 abc 94mmm4k   53g      NaN  10     4      NaN   NaN
  7   354 abc 94mmm4k   53g      NaN  10     4      NaN   NaN
  ```
- With `fillna('')`:

  ```
  df1 = df.fillna('').merge(df2, on=['x_1','x_2','x_3','x_4','x_5','ID'], how='left')
  ```

  Result:

  ```
      x_1 x_2     x_3   x_4      x_5  ID  cost    count   sum
  0   159 xyz 883nne2 28h93   lightz  10     2        2     7
  1   159 xyz 883nne2 28h93   lightz  10     5        2     7
  2   354 abc 94mmm4k          heavy  15     2        2     3
  3   354 abc 94mmm4k          heavy  15     1        2     3
  4   354 abc 94mmm4k 455h            15     7        1     7
  5   354 abc 94mmm4k          super  3      2        1     2
  6   354 abc 94mmm4k 53g             10     4        2     8
  7   354 abc 94mmm4k 53g             10     4        2     8
  ```

The actual results will differ depending on your exact use-case but this demonstrates the most likely issue in the question.

Comment: Ty for the effort here. The issue you mentioned was correct. I didn't not take into account NAN values in both DataFrames. I appreciate you taking the time to explore a solution

Comment: @Aldo: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly suspect that one of your index columns are mismatched between an object and a numeric type. Please add this prior to your merge code to check.

```
for i in range(len(y_merge_cols)):
     assert y_merge_cols[i].dtype == x_merge_cols[i].dtype,\
          'Expected type {} got {}'.format(y_merge_cols[i].dtype,x_merge_cols[i].dtype)
```